# How to add limit option in Magento API call

Tags: magento

I am creating web service for my store. I am using magento API to collect product list from store. But it display all the 500 records. And i want it 25 records per page. What to add in API call? Or What filter will be apply for this?

//create soap object
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhsot/magento/api/soap/?wsdl');

```
// create authorized session id using api user name and api key
// $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test_admin', '12345678');

    $filters = array(


    );


 // Get list of product
$productlist = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));

print_r($productlist );
```

Answer (score 0):

that didn't work, can you limit it by id like:

```
$filters = array('id'=>array("gteq"=>1), 'id'=>array("lteq"=>1000));
```

that way you could add some paging?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I struggled with this. I've created my own SOAP API endpoint which does exactly the same as the default catalogProductList function but has an extra param. See the code below:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter($this->_getStoreId($store))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
if($limit) {
    $collection->setOrder('updated_at', 'ASC');
    $collection->setPageSize($limit);
}
/** @var $apiHelper Mage_Api_Helper_Data */
$apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
$filters = $apiHelper->parseFilters($filters, $this->_filtersMap);
try {
    foreach ($filters as $field => $value) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $value);
    }
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
}
$result = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $result[] = array(
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
        'name'       => $product->getName(),
        'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
        'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
        'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
        'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds(),
        'updated_at'  => $product->getUpdatedAt(),
        'created_at'  => $product->getCreatedAt()
    );
}
return $result;
```

And from there we keep track of the last updated_at value and use that as a filter to get the next [LIMIT] items. By default updated_at and created_at are not in the response and the list is not orderred by updated_at so I've added this.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure of this but you could try this, as the API is working with collections and this is the way to limit a collection size

```
$filters = array(
    'setPageSize' => 10
);
```